# Method of Inputting strings a specific number of times based on an integer input

Tags: input

Im trying to create a function that takes a positive integer as an argument, then takes that integer as a number of inputs. Each input will be on a new line. These inputs(strings) will then be appended to a list and returned

this is what the function should look like:

```
4

a

b

c

d

["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

```
2

q

r

["q", "r"]
```

---

Comment: Do you want any code monkey to do your homework for you ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it don't show any search effort, nor code

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use 4 methods for this problem:

1. main
2. Method that creates and fills an array
3. A printer
4. Used for testing the program (supplies array length) to make sure it works

//

// You did not specify, but I am assuming java and that you want to use arrays

// I have coded this entire program, and will be willing to fix/help with whatever code you post

// Also remember to import scanner.

//

1) Main is simple, just call the methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = test();
    String[] array = arrayCreator(length);
    printArray(array);
}
```

2) Now create the array:

```
- public static String[] arrayCreator(int length){
- create a new scanner
- make a new array with the int "length" defining its length.
- Prompt user to enter strings
- simple for loop with i being less than length
- inside for loop:
    - new string getting input from scanner
    - array[i] = temp;
- return the array
```

3) Print the array:

```
- public static void printArray(String[] array){
- int length = array.length;
- String temp = "";
- System.out.print("[");
- for loop with i < length
- nested in for loop:
    - if statement with i equaling one less than the length:
        - temp = array[i];
        - System.out.print("\""+temp+"\"]");
    - else statement:
        - temp = array[i];
        - System.out.print("\""+temp+"\", ");
```

4) Tester method:

```
- public static int test(){
- Create a new Scanner (remember to import scanner)
- prompt for array size
- new int that takes the input
- return the int
```

Comment: My mistake for not specifying, I am working in python

Comment: Alright, well I wrote the program, but in java. Unfortunately I don't know python so I cannot help you any further. Best of luck.